# A lot of whitespace beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am doing web scraping using beautifulsoup. The web page has the following source:

```
<td>\n<a href="http://aaa.com">Charles</a>\r\n                         (hello)\r\n                            </td>,
<td>\n<a href="http://bbb.com">Diane</a>\r\n                           (hi)\r\n                            </td>,
<td>\n<a href="http://ccc.com">Kevin</a>\r\n                           (how are you doing)\r\n                            </td>
```

I use the following codes to print two values. They work just fine.

```
for item in soup.find_all("td"):
    print item.find('a').text
    print item.find('a').next_sibling
```

The problem is when I save the outputs in a csv file, the second column has no value. It appears because there is a lot of whitespace. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find all the [next text siblings](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling), join them and strip:

```
"".join(item.find('a').find_next_siblings(text=True)).strip()
```